# Cannot call custom function loaded from script using C/C++ MathLink

Tags: functions, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

I am using MathLink with C/C++ on a Unix system in order to call a *Mathematica* (version 9) function and get the result.

The function I need to call is a personal function of mine `MyFunct[x,y,z]`. The function takes three arguments and will return a `Real`. This function is defined in `myscript.m` file at this path: `/home/myuser/Documents/mym/myscript.m`.

I have the following C code:

```c
#include <mathlink.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  MLENV env = (MLENV)0;
  MLINK ml = (MLINK)0;

  // Init and open
  env = MLInitialize((char*)0);
  int err = 0;
  char* argv[5];
  argv[0] = "ml";
  argv[1] = "-linkmode";
  argv[2] = "launch";
  argv[3] = "-linkname";
  argv[4] = "/usr/local/Mathematica/9.0/Executables/MathLink";
  *link = MLOpenArgcArgv(*env, 5, argv, &err);

  fprintf(stdout, "All ok!\n");

  // Putting function
  MLPutFunction(ml, "N", 1);
  MLPutFunction(ml, "Cos", 1);
  MLPutInteger(ml, 2);
  MLEndPacket(ml);
  MLFlush(ml);

  // Getting
  int pkt;
  while ((pkt = MLNextPacket(ml),pkt) && pkt != RETURNPKT) {
    MLNewPacket(ml);
    if (MLError(ml)) fprintf(stdout, "Error!\n");
  }
  double r = 0;
  MLGetReal(ml, &r);
  fprintf(stdout, "Got %f!\n", r);

  // Close and deinit
  envCloseLink(&ml);
  fprintf(stdout, "Closed!\n");
  envDeInitEnv(&env);
  fprintf(stdout, "Deinitialized!\n");

  fprintf(stdout, "Over!\n");
}
```

The above code works! Now consider the following:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  MLENV env = (MLENV)0;
  MLINK ml = (MLINK)0;

  // Init and open
  env = MLInitialize((char*)0);
  int err = 0;
  char* argv[5];
  argv[0] = "ml";
  argv[1] = "-linkmode";
  argv[2] = "launch";
  argv[3] = "-linkname";
  argv[4] = "/usr/local/Mathematica/9.0/Executables/MathLink";
  *link = MLOpenArgcArgv(*env, 5, argv, &err);

  fprintf(stdout, "All ok!\n");

  // CALLING 'GET' ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  fprintf(stdout, "Putting [GET]...\n");
  if (!MLPutFunction(ml, "Get", 1)) fprintf(stdout, "Err!\n");;
  if (!MLPutString(ml, "/home/myuser/Documents/mym/myscript.m")) fprintf(stdout, "Err!\n");
  MLEndPacket(ml);
  if (!MLFlush(ml)) fprintf(stdout, "Err!\n");
  int pkt = 0;
  while ((pkt = MLNextPacket(ml),pkt) && pkt != RETURNPKT) {
    MLNewPacket(ml);
    if (MLError(ml)) fprintf(stdout, "Error!\n");
  }
  // END //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // CALLING FUNCT ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  fprintf(stdout, "Calling impulse...\n");
  MLPutFunction(ml, "MyFunct", 3);
  MLPutInteger(ml, 1);
  MLPutInteger(ml, 4);
  MLPutInteger(ml, 2);
  MLEndPacket(ml);
  MLFlush(ml);
  int pkt2 = 0;
  while ((pkt2 = MLNextPacket(ml),pkt2) && pkt2 != RETURNPKT) {
    MLNewPacket(ml);
    if (MLError(ml)) fprintf(stdout, "Error!\n");
  }
  double r = 0;
  if (!MLGetReal(ml, &r)) fprintf(stdout, "Error in getting!\n"); // LINE REF1
  fprintf(stdout, "Got %f\n", r);
  // END //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Close and deinit
  envCloseLink(&ml);
  fprintf(stdout, "Closed!\n");
  envDeInitEnv(&env);
  fprintf(stdout, "Deinitialized!\n");

  fprintf(stdout, "Over!\n");
}
```

I got an error in `LINE REF1`. I understood that the problem is the `CALLING 'GET'` block. If I delete this block and call a *Mathematica* built in function  (like in the previous code), I get no errors. But if I insert the block `CALLING 'GET'` and then try to call one of the functions defined in my external file or a built in *Mathematica* function, errors are raised at the specified line (`LINE REF1`).

Maybe I've made a mistake when trying to perform two sequential operations on the link... How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you call `Get`, you run a packet loop, waiting for the `ReturnPacket`. But you never read or discard the contents of that `ReturnPacket`. That means that the whatever expression that `Get` returns (it will be the result of last evaluation in the myscript.m file, perhaps the symbol `Null`) is still waiting on the link. Then you call your function and wait for the result with the `pkt2` loop. But the first call to `MLNextPacket()` in that loop will return 0 because it is a MathLink error to call `MLNextPacket()` when data from a previous packet is still waiting. If you move your `MLError()` call in that `while` loop to after the loop (where it belongs), you would see that an error condition has already occurred, before the call to `MLGetReal()`.

The fix is simple: a call to `MLNewPacket()` after your packet loop for the `Get` call (line 30), to throw away the contents of the first `ReturnPacket`.

Answer (score 6):

Forgive me my ignorance to not try your sample code and instead give you an idea for a completely different approach. Since you are just launching a MathKernel in your *MathLink* program, why don't you use the `-run` option, to load your package during the launch?

You can test this directly in the front end

```
kernel = LinkLaunch[
  First[$CommandLine] <> 
   " -mathlink -run 'Get[\"CompiledFunctionTools`\"]'"];

read[] := If[LinkReadyQ[kernel], LinkRead[kernel]];

read[]
(* InputNamePacket["In[1]:= "] *)

LinkWrite[kernel, Unevaluated[CompilePrint::usage]]

read[]
(* ReturnPacket["CompilePrint[ cfun] prints a human readable form of a
compiled function."]
*)
```

As you see the `CompiledFunctionTools` package was successfully loaded. Therefore, the only thing you have to do is to include this in your `argv` and you should be done.

Comment: Or why not drive the whole C program from Mathematica and use `MLEvaluate` for callbacks?  It may simplify things further.

Comment: @halirutan: Thanks a lot for your reply, yes it is a different approach, but you provided a really interesting point of view. Thanks a lot