# Error loading shared library libML64i3.so

Tags: external-calls

I'm trying to call Mathematica from C. I'm following the example https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32864/14301 with http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkDeveloperGuide-Unix.html#725481284

The code I have is:
mlcall.c (identical to what i linked)

```
#include <mathlink.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MLENV env;
    MLINK link;
    int errno;
    int packet;

    env = MLInitialize(0);

    /* consider using MLOpenString instead here: */    

    link = MLOpenArgcArgv(env, argc, argv, &errno);

    MLActivate(link);

    /* send 42+137 using the full form Plus[42, 137] */
    MLPutFunction(link, "Plus", 2);
    MLPutInteger(link, 42);
    MLPutInteger(link, 137);
    MLEndPacket(link);

    /* get packets until we find a ReturnPacket or error */
    while ((packet = MLNextPacket(link)) && packet != RETURNPKT)
        MLNewPacket(link);

    if (MLError(link))
        printf("error.\n");
    else {
        int result;
        MLGetInteger(link, &result); /* we know that the result is an integer in this case */
        printf("result: %d\n", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and makefile:

```
MLINKDIR = /opt/Mathematica-9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit
SYS=Linux-x86-64
CADDSDIR = ${MLINKDIR}/${SYS}/CompilerAdditions

INCDIR = ${CADDSDIR}
LIBDIR = ${CADDSDIR}

MLLIB = ML64i3

EXTRALIBS = -lm -lpthread -lrt -lstdc++ # Set these with appropriate libs for your system.

mlcall: mlcall.c
    $(CC) -O mlcall.c -I$(INCDIR) -L$(LIBDIR) -l${MLLIB} ${EXTRALIBS} -o $@

clean:
    rm mlcall
```

Output of make is:

```
cc -O mlcall.c -I/opt/Mathematica-9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -L/opt/Mathematica-9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -lML64i3 -lm -lpthread -lrt -lstdc++  -o mlcall
```

So no errors, but when I try to run mlcall with either `./mlcall` or `./mlcall -linkmode launch -linkname "/usr/bin/MathKernel"` I get the following error:

```
./mlcall: error while loading shared libraries: libML64i3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do have `libML64i3.so` in the directory `/opt/Mathematica-9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions -L/opt/Mathematica-9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions` and I also tried to copy it to the directory I was running `mlcall` in. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux you can add the directory containing this library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

A semi-automated way to do this from a command prompt is this:

```sh
MATHLINK=$(dirname $(readlink -f $(which math)))/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MATHLINK
```

You can use this merthod of detecting the location in a shell script that will start your program.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Not that it matters, but is there any particular reason for not using two `dirname`-s or `/../..`?

Comment: @user1335014 Can you write out the command you're thinking of?  To tell the truth, I'm not good at shell scripting.  I had to use this in the past, figured it out then, then copied and pasted here.

Comment: I think that `$(dirname $(readlink -f $(which math)))/../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions` is equivalent to `$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which math))))/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions` and `$(readlink -f $(which math))/../../SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions`. But as I said that it doesn't matter. I'm not that home in shell myself either and thought that there might be some detail in this that I don't understand.

Comment: @user1335014 Your first example looks correct.  The second isn't though.  That's because `readlink` does not return a directory name.  It returns a file name.  `filename/..` makes no sense.

Comment: @user1335014 Another think: `readlink` seems to work differently on different OS ... I wrote this for Linux, but on OS X (and I assume BSD) the `-f` option has a different meaning.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. What confused me is that if you run `echo $(readlink -f $(which math))` then it prints absolute path (in my case `/opt/Mathematica-9.0/Executables/math`).