# MathLink error while calling a custom Mathematica function - MLGet out of sequence

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink

I am trying to call Mathematica 10 from F#.  Following the C# sample code found in the Mathematica directory, I have written the following F# code:

```c
type TestClass() =
    member this.AddNumsWithWM (m : int) (n : int) : int =
        let ml = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink()
        ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer()
        ml.PutFunction("EvaluatePacket", 1)
        ml.PutFunction("testFunc", 2) // IF BUILT-IN FUNCTION LIKE Plus, THEN NO ERROR
        ml.Put(m)
        ml.Put(n)
        ml.EndPacket()
        ml.WaitForAnswer() |> ignore
        let res = ml.GetInteger() // THE ERROR OCCURS HERE FOR CUSTOM FUNCTION
        ml.Close()
        res
```

The Mathematica function `testFunc` is simply:

```
testFunc[m_Integer, n_Integer] := m + 2 * n;
```

But when I call the function `AddNumsWithWM 2 3`, I get the following error at the line indicated above:

```
Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkException' occurred in Wolfram.NETLink.dll
Additional information: Error code: 3.
```

I don't understand, because the sample C#, from which this has been translated literally, works.  Any idea why I would get the above error?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

I have verified something else.  If I use a built-in function like `Plus` instead of my custom function `testFunc`, the code works.

So, then, I guess my question would be, Why does the code not work for a custom function?  I would be very grateful for pointers on what I need to do differently in order to call a custom function.

I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Have you solved this problem？I also face the problem in .NETLink programing. and i realize that even a built-in function like Plus can not be used like the sample in the document of .NETLink API. If you have solve the problem, can you give me some advice？Thank U

Answer (score 2):

`testFunc[]` needs to be defined prior to being called. I don't use .NETLink, so I can't guarantee if the following will work, but try `ml.Evaluate("testFunc[m_Integer, n_Integer] := m + 2 * n;")` to do so. I'm not sure if this returns any packets and needs to be followed up with an `ml.WaitAndDiscardAnswer()`. In any case, if you have many custom functions, I suggest putting them in a package to be loaded via an `ml.Evaluate("Get[package];")` to reduce overhead from multiple .NETLink calls.